# Formatting the text in a table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need some basic css help. I attempted to style the cells of a table using a css stylesheet, but its not working

The code of the table is:

```
<table> 
<tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
   <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
     <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
      <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
       <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
        <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
         <tr><td><p style="font-size:13px"><a href="mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX">XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p style="font-size:13px">XXXXXXX   </p></td></tr> 
                  </table>
```

The only way I got the text to not go to browser defaults was to explicitly state it on every single cell, which seems like a waste of load time (as miniscule as it is). Is there a way to set the size of the text for the entire table? It's is all the same size.

I tried putting the table inside a `<p>` and then styling it using a CSS class, but it was not working. Not sure if it matters, but I am using XHTML 1.0.

Comment: Would this help you? `td, td a {
    font-size:13px;
}`

Comment: Styles like this are supposed to inherit, so you should be able to put a style attribute in the table tag. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/er9wY/) Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: @MrLister that was not working. Its working now though

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would add the class to the table:

```
<table class='myFormat'><tr>....</tr></table>
```

Then:

```
table.myFormat tr td { font-size: 13px; }
```

Can you tell me what browsers this is in?

Comment: This did not work for me.  I wanted the style to apply to the headers as well, so I added 'th' next to 'tr' and 'td' in the example above -- that broke the style entirely for some reason,

So what I wound up doing is just having the following in my CSS:

.myFormat { font-size: 13px; }

That let the font-size apply to everything in any table with 'class="myFormat"' set.  Not just the table-data, but the headers as well.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
td { font-size: 13px }
```

OR

```
td.myfontsize { font-size: 13px ; }
```

then using:

```
class="myfontsize"
```

applied to your td tags?

Comment: Well if you use something like:  td { font-size: 13px }  that would apply a blanket style to all cells in any table. However make sure that's what you want for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<table>` to `<table style="font-size: 13px;">`. That should change all of the text inside of the table.

Otherwise, you can just add a class or id to it and use it to style the rows as said by @user1086498.